# Customize Visual Studio XSD Generation Rules

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2019, xsd.exe

I'm generating my XSDs by drag-and-dropping the tables onto the XSD Design view in Visual Studio 2019. For the most part this is generating what I need, however I've noticed there's an issue, it's not generating my foreign keys as foreign keys but as relationships, which means ON CASCADE DELETE isn't working. Is there a way to run the tool, either through the GUI or command line, that generates my foreign keys as foreign keys with cascading deletes intact?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your foreign keys as foreign keys with cascading deletes intact, you can refer to the under steps:

First, right click on XMLSchema.xsd file and choose Open With…
[image]

Second, choose DataSet Editor.
[image]

Then, right click on the table choose Add-->Relation.
[image]

Finally you can change your foreign key and modify the deletion rules in the lowed part.
[image]

Comment: When I bring the tables over from the database the connections are automatically generated, so I don't need to create them, I can update the existing relationships. What I was hoping for was a way to have the relations generate as foreign keys so I don't have to update them manually. Is this possible?